# What methods existed for boosting caster level in D&D 3.0?

Tags: dnd-3e

What methods existed for boosting caster level in D&D 3.0 (**before 3.5**)? I'm looking for straight boosts, so something like the good domain boost to good spells only is not relevant (unless there's a way to make it apply to all spells).

I know of Karma beads (from the *necklace of prayer beads*) and the spell *death knell*. It's hard to believe that's all there is though. ("Gain levels as a caster!" doesn't count.)

I'm playing in a D&D 3e-only campaign, so material before or after is not acceptable.

I have not been able to find any consolidated list or useful discussion with google.

Comment: This is kinda broad; what are you using this increased caster level for? What classes does the character have?

Comment: @Chemus I had hoped to get a list of all the ways to boost caster level in 3.0. I think it would be a short list, because I don't think there are many. I've built several different characters recently where I looked for ways to boost CL, but couldn't find any (except the two I mentioned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feats:

I am not aware of any feats that allow you to flatly boost your caster level in 3rd edition.

Items:

The version of the legendary sword Blackrazor found in the 3rd edition *Arms and Equipment Guide* will grant a boost to caster level across the board; though the effect is labeled as similar to *death knell*, the description actually uses the word "similar," so it should stack with the spell.

Terran Brandy from *The Book of Vile Darkness* temporarily raises caster level, though it also inflicts 2 points of Constitution damage.  Liquid Pain (same book) will increase the caster level of one spell at a time.

A Vial of the Last Gasp, from *Song and Silence*, gives another temporary boost to caster level, among other things.

The ioun stone mentioned previously is the orange ioun stone, but that is unfortunately from the 3.5 edition of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*.

Spells:

For 3rd edition, *death knell* is pretty much it.

As a final note, you get far more mileage out of trying to increase your caster level for specific spells or spell types than you do trying for a blanket increase- maybe consider specializing to take advantage of that?

Answer (score -3):

There's also an ioun stone that boosts caster level by +1.

If you are multiclassed, there is a feat to boost your caster level, but not to exceed your total character level.

Comment: Hi Cayzle, and welcome to the site. I see from your Informed badge that you've checked out our [tour]; thanks for doing that. Can you name which Ioun stone it is and where it can be found, and which feat that is and where that feat that can be found?

Comment: The feat to which you refer is almost-certainly Practiced Spellcaster in *Complete Arcane* and/or *Complete Divine*, which is a D&D 3.5e feat, not available in D&D 3.0.

Comment: I really can't upvote this without some specifics.  Which ioun stone?  What feat?

Comment: In 3.0, the Orange Prism Ioun stone adds +1 to caster level, the Heart of Fire Ioun stone adds +2 to the caster level of fire spells.